# Doctrine Class not found

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

please check my code.

i have a composer.json

```
{
"require": {
    "doctrine/orm": "2.4.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "2.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"": "src/"}
}}
```

bootstrap.php

```
 use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode,null,null,false);
$conn = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname' => 'ClinicaDental'
);
$entityManager = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

cli-config.php

```
<?php
// cli-config.php
require_once "bootstrap.php";

$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($entityManager)
));

return $helperSet;
```

and Products.php

```
<?php



use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Products
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Products
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

and this file create_products.php

```
<?php
// create_product.php
require_once "bootstrap.php";
require_once './src/Products.php';



$newProductName = $argv[1];

$product = new Product();
$product->setName($newProductName);

$entityManager->persist($product);
$entityManager->flush();

echo "Created Product with ID " . $product->getId() . "\n";
```

run through the terminal file "create product.php" and I receive this error:

```
HP Fatal error:  Class 'Product' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ClinicaDental/create_product.php on line 10
```

Class Not Found.

Please help me with this file.
Regards

Comment: Wouldn't it be `new Products();` ? (plural)

Comment: You named your class Products :)

Comment: Thanks guys. new Products(); is correct

Comment: @Farkie thanks,  the class name is wrong in my application.

Comment: @Pete thanks you, is correct your solution.

Comment: What browser do you use? I'd recommend checking PHPStorm, it greatly improved in last few years. It has 1-month free version.

Comment: Browser? You mean IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be new Products(); ? (plural) – Farkie Oct 26 at 18:52 
1
You named your class Products :) – Pete Oct 26 at 18:53
1
Thanks guys. new Products(); is correct – ronal vasquez Oct 26 at 19:00

@Farkie thanks, the class name is wrong in my application. – ronal vasquez Oct 26 at 19:02
1
@Pete thanks you, is correct your solution. – ronal vasquez Oct 26 at 19:04

What browser do you use? I'd recommend checking PHPStorm, it greatly improved in last few years. It has 1-month free version. – Tomáš Votruba Oct 26 at 19:13

Browser? You mean IDE? – Farkie Oct 26 at 19:36